# Python iterating through directories and updating dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, nested-loops

Dictionary "d" consists only of the latest iterated subfolder keys and values when I want to add all folders. I don't get why my dictionary starts updating from empty dictionary after folder changes.

```
import os
from os.path import join

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    d = dict()
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.txt') :
            value_thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            key_size = os.path.getsize(value_thefile)
            d.update({key_size:value_thefile})
print d
```

Comment: Because you assign it an empty dictionary on each iteration of the outer loop...? That's what `d = dict()` does.

Comment: As @jpmc26 indicates, try putting the `d=dict()` instruction before the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary `d` keeps getting set to a new empty dict for each iteration of the outer `for` loop. ie It keeps getting re-initialised to `{}`:

```
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    d = dict()    # this makes d == {} for each iteration of os.walk('.')
    for filename in files:
        ...
```

Instead, initialise it outside the loops, like this:

```
d = dict()    # this makes d == {} only at the start
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        ...  # rest of your code
```